# Fogger in Ubuntu 14.04 is not working

Tags: webapps

I used [Fogger](https://launchpad.net/fogger) in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and it worked great. Recently, I installed 14.04 LTS, and in 14.04 I was unable to install Fogger.

I added the ppa from Terminal: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:loneowais/fogger` It added, but updating shows an error and Fogger is not installing in 14.04.

I really liked Fogger, and I don't want to use webapps as alternatives.

Comment: May be the ppa is for 12.04. There is lot of difference between Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was playing around with making web app like I used to do with prism.

I just read about fogger today.  I installed by downloading the deb for latest version.  I installed with gbebi.  But had to run `sudo apt install -f` after that to get completely installed.

It is also possible to create a .desktop file and have it execute

```
webbrowser-app --chromeless --maximized http://www.yoursite-url.com
```

If you want to be able to mouse-up on bottom of window for path... back... etc, remove --chromeless from execute line.

The "chrome" of this app only displays temporarily so the chromeless aspect is likely not necessary for the most part.

Comment: thank you that worked i downloaded .deb file and installed with gdebi and had to run sudo apt install -f but its working fine

Comment: Would you mind adding where you find the .deb? I believe it would make the answer more complete.

Comment: Found .deb in launchpad https://launchpad.net/~loneowais/+archive/ubuntu/fogger/+packages downloaded 13.10 deb package

Comment: webbrowser-app works really good, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question:
Sadly, Fogger is Dead and it died around the time of Ubuntu 12.10. "loneowais", abandoned the project pretty much immediately after the Ubuntu App Showdown was over.

Source: I was a part of the FogApp Authors and wrote multiple FogApps in the project.

---

**webbrowser-app** is a great suggestion and I'd also like to point out that it supports the "**--fullscreen**" option to start in not just maximized but completely fullscreen, which is cool for some scenarios.

webbrowser-app also "**--app-id=**" which is a controller for Sessions, it allows you to give a unique identifier to create a persistent session for the identifier and if you reuse that identifier again it will return with that session. This feature allows you to have multiple instances of the same webapp logged in with multiple different accounts. This would be really cool for say someone who has many different Gmail accounts.

---

There are some more options to create Web-App Desktop Applications as well.

**Epiphany**, aka GNOME's Web, has support for Web-App Desktop Applications including multiple sessions.

**Midori** has support for Web-App Desktop Applications including multiple sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is much simpler than what everyone is making it look like. Add the PPA as usual, then go to your Software Sources app and manually edit the end of the URL path after `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/loneowais/fogger/` by replacing `ubuntu precise main` (or whatever PPA you choose, I recommend choosing the closest up-to-date one) to your version of Ubuntu, which is Ubuntu Trusty.

Your end result should look like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/loneowais/fogger/ubuntu trusty main
```

There you go! Now just perform a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install fogger` and we should be good to go! :)

Comment: Fogger PPA is not available for trusty see this page https://launchpad.net/~loneowais/+archive/ubuntu/fogger/+packages

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Since Fogger ☁️ is no-more, why not try an alternative?
I recommend trying Nativefier, which runs in Node.JS - a JavaScript program library on top of an open-source Chromium browser - packaged in one.

⚠️ Use of Nativefier will require some Terminal input, but it's just a few commands and can be learned easily using their Readme on the GitHub page below:
https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier

Instructions for download and install of Nativefier is on the site above too, of course.